# A compromised USB

Tags: malware, usb

Assuming that a given USB drive is compromised(infected), what's the best way to deal with it? I mean, obviously, the solution is to nuke(format) the drive. But for that, the device needs to be connected to a PC. Isn't it possible for the malware to spread from the drive to the PC? Sure, antivirus programs might help but they aren't perfect. A particularly nasty piece of malware can utilize that time windows to infect the host PC. What's the foolproof way to deal with such an situation?

Comment: A hammer. USB sticks are dirt cheap and you don't want to risk your data.

Comment: Won't booting into a live CD(Linux) help?In that case,the USB will only have access to the running OS(which isn't the main OS)?

Comment: And the running OS has access to the common hardware. The risk ain't worth it. Of course, if you have a throwaway airgapped rig that can be studied by your forensics team, by all means go for it.

Comment: How could you stop the USB from mounting the hard drive or modifying your BIOS?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As USB drives can be compromised in ways that are [not identifiable by an antivirus and not corrected by formatting the drive](https://srlabs.de/badusb/), the only foolproof solution is to destroy the drive.

Comment: Great, but what if you care about the files that were on it?

Comment: @phyrfox - there are strategies that will reduce your risk but the question specifically asks for `the foolproof way`. There is no foolproof way short of destruction.

Comment: Unless you're foolish enough to *boot* from the USB stick that's infected, Linux is the foolproof solution. I've safely recovered many sticks, hard drives, etc, this way.

Comment: @phyrfox - what if the USB pretends to be a USB keyboard or some other non-drive device that the system interacts with automatically?

Comment: If you really needed to recover a file, you could always use something really cheap and expendable like a raspberry pi to extract your documents. You just have to make sure the files you retrieve haven't been tampered with.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, you don't want to stick an infected USB stick into a Windows OS or Mac OS running system, since merely plugging in can cause infection. Instead, if you suspect your drive is infected, grab a Live CD for a specialized Linux distro that has anti-virus capabilities, such as [Avira Rescue System](http://www.avira.com/en/download/product/avira-rescue-system), boot your system into that secure environment, and then scan the USB drive that way. You can also safely copy data off the infected USB stick (but be careful for infected applications you might copy). This is assuming you want to *rescue* your data. The code can't harm your system if it can run in the OS that's provided (e.g. Windows viruses can't run in Linux, as there are binary differences). Otherwise, if you don't care about the data, simply physically destroy the drive and get a new one.

Comment: How would you know that the USB won't work on both windows and linux? How could you stop the USB from mounting the hard drive?

Comment: @NeilSmithline Most Linux systems that are use to do rescues are hardened against viruses. Viruses can't operate without the cooperation of the host system, because, until they're loaded in memory and executed by the system, they're nothing more than bits of data in a mass storage device. Windows is insecure because it automatically "runs" specially formatted drives, and Mac OS has a similar problem. A secure Linux system won't allow the code to run, and definitely won't allow mounting without user permission.

Comment: But if the USB drive is modified so that it acts as a USB keyboard, it can execute type commands into Linux.

Comment: phyrfox, please study the matter just a bit more. Your advice is dangerous. It may work 9 times out of 10, but otherwise it'll wreak havoc on the unfortunate person who blindly followed your ill-considered advice.

Comment: Grab a live CD and pull the hard drive. If you leave the hard drive in, all bets are off.

Comment: @DeerHunter I accepted your challenge, and did my reading; I actually perused the BadUSB code and various articles. The entire system is about the infection of *devices*, not *hosts*, which is an important distinction. Unless the virus on the USB stick supports a particular flavor of Linux, *and* Linux chooses to let it run, your actual hardware is safe. Yes, it's possible that BadUSB will make it impossible to recover your data, act like a keyboard, etc. It won't, however, infect the host without the OS's cooperation. I stand by this answer unless you have a specific proof or POC otherwise.